# Angular interceptor to set header authorization causes error in return of api

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, authorization, angular-http-interceptors

I have created an interceptor to set the header authorization:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    var httpAuthInterceptor = [ 'AuthStateService', function(AuthStateService) {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          var user = AuthStateService.getCurrentUser();
          var token = AuthStateService._getToken();
          if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + user + ':' + token;
          }
          return config || $q.when(config);
        }
      };
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(httpAuthInterceptor);
}]);
```

So, when I call the service below, the return of service (data) is OK 3 times (OKOKOK).

```
.factory("connectAPI", ['$http', 'config', 'loginAPI', function($http, config, loginAPI){
  var _connect = function(callBack){
    var param = {
        user: loginAPI.getUser(),
        pass: loginAPI.getPass()
      };

    $http.get(config.baseUrl + 'connect/user/' + param.user + '/pass/' + param.pass)
      .success(function(data){
        callBack(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
      });
  };

  return {
    connect: _connect
  };
}])
```

My api method:

```
@Path("user/{user}/pass/{pass}")
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  + ";charset=utf-8"})
public String getUserData(@PathParam("user") String user, @PathParam("pass") String pass) {
  if (user != "" && pass != ""){
    //test
    return "OK"
  }
  return "NOK"
}
```

I have checked it and the api method was calling 3 times. I don't know what is happening.

When I comment the header authorization line, the api method is calling just 1 time. What is wrong?

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    var httpAuthInterceptor = [ 'AuthStateService', function(AuthStateService) {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          var user = AuthStateService.getCurrentUser();
          var token = AuthStateService._getToken();
          //if (token) {
          //  config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + user + ':' + token;
          //}
          return config || $q.when(config);
        }
      };
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(httpAuthInterceptor);
}]);
```

Comment: what does *"only calling one line"* mean? Why are strings being returned and not JSON?

Comment: Using callbacks instead of returning promises makes your code difficult to analyze. Consider returning promises and chaining from the `.then` method of the promise. You will get the same funtionality with the added benefit that race conditiions can be avoided.

Comment: Hi, Georgeawg, it's just a test. I really don't think because I have used callback instead of promise is the key of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it was a problem in my web.xml, I duplicated my filter unintentionally.